# Possible to use Sub-Functions in Apps Scripts (Google)

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to use Sub-Functions in Apps Scripts from Google ?
Like call a function with `Monday.Lock` or something similar ?

```
function MONDAY () {
function .LOCK() {
    xxxxxxxxxx
  }
}
function .UNLOCK() {
    xxxxxxxxxx
  }
}
function .DELETE() {
    xxxxxxxxxx
  }
}
```

Comment: Sure, if `MONDAY` is a object `{}` . But what you're looking for is a `Class` and methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how to create an object with the methods you mention.

```
class MONDAY {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  LOCK() {
    this.name = "LOCK";
  }
  UNLOCK() {
    this.name = "UNLOCK";
  }
  DELETE() {
    this.name = "DELETE";
  }
}

function testMONDAY() {
  let day = new MONDAY("hello");
  console.log(day.name);
  day.LOCK();
  console.log(day.name);
  day.UNLOCK();
  console.log(day.name);
  day.DELETE();
  console.log(day.name);
}
```

---

```
10:06:02 AM Notice  Execution started
10:06:03 AM Info    hello
10:06:03 AM Info    LOCK
10:06:03 AM Info    UNLOCK
10:06:03 AM Info    DELETE
10:06:03 AM Notice  Execution completed
```

Reference

- [Classes](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_classes.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Script is modern JavaScript with full support to classes that let you do what you are asking. See [Clean Code JavaScript](https://github.com/ryanmcdermott/clean-code-javascript#classes) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).